# Parsing problem with hpricot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parsing, hpricot

I have an XML that looks like this:

```
<data>
  <image src="http://www.someweb.com/something.png"/>
</data>
```

What is the correct way to use hpricot to extact just 'http://www.someweb.com/something.png'? The closest I can get is this...

```
>>(doc/"image").first
=> {emptyelem <image src="http://www.someweb.com/something.png">}
```

I've read the hpricot README on github and googled, but haven't found anything yet. Thanks in advance for any answers!

Answer (score 0):

```
(doc/'data image').first.attributes['src']
```

Comment: It's pretty low for an admin to delete your own comment, and mine in the process, because it would shed some light why a valid answer has been downvoted.